# How to enable/disable hyperlinkfiled after first click on it

Tags: c#, hyperlink, asp.net-4.0

Hi coder I have a hyperlinkfield in my grid-view. When the user clicks on that link it will redirect him to another page. This is my hyperlinkfield code:

```
 <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" 
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/User/Form.aspx?ID={0}&buttonValue=Update" 
                HeaderText="Query" NavigateUrl="~/User/Form.aspx" Text="Select"/>
```

i have a bit value which is false when details update after first click so What I want is: If the user click on it a second time bit is false so it shouldn't work. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So when the user is on a new page, the new page has the same link? And he should not be able klick on it again? Can't you remove it from the new page?

Comment: when user click on link it will redirect to a Update details page and when it press update button on update Page it will redirect back to 1st page when it redirect back to 1st page so i want when it redirect back to first page or when it open that page next time hyperlink will be disabled

Comment: ah ok, but what if the user made a mistake and has to go there again?

Comment: Then he have to go to his/her manager to make it correct basically it a role based application manager wants user to make it correct at first attempt thats why i want to diable it on second time only for user not for manager

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing in a QueryString `buttonValue` when you redirect, you could use this to determine where the user is in the process and disable the button accordingly.

E.g.

```
if(Request.QueryString.Get("buttonValue") == "Update")
{
   yourhyperlink.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: i dont want to disable button i want to disable hyperlink

Comment: `yourbutton` is just an example, this would work the exact same way for a hyperlink...

Comment: i didn't get what u r trying to say c i used query string to pass value of that particular id to another page and buttonValue=Update is used for different purpose

Comment: Pass in a different querystring param/value then??

Comment: if you wana see my full code then go to that link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609508/how-to-notify-a-user-after-some-time-that-gridview-is-updated this is update page code and if you want my gridview code i can show that you to

Comment: and more over this hyperlink is in gridview

Answer (score 0):

Finally got my answer

I add a bit datatype in my database so that when user enter details in form and press submit button bit become "true" and when click on link and update details bit become "false" when bit become false write code on RowDataBoung

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string url = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Bit").ToString();
        if (url =="False")
        {
            e.Row.Cells[15].Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```